# multi level menu with MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Can someone guide me on how to build a multi level menu with MUI? I mean something like this image below:

[image: A menu from YouTube, showing multiple items. Some of the items have an arrow at the end of the item, indicating a submenu is available. One of which reads 'Appearance: Device theme']

[image: A submenu from the 'Appearance' menu item show above. It has three menu items without any arrows showing further submenus. One item, 'device theme' has a tick or checkmark at the start of the item]

I have designed the exact same thing with the `Menu` component from MUI but I want to this menu react to clicking. So for example if I click on the 'Appearance' `MenuItem` in the first image it goes to second image with a slide effect transition on the same container.

```
<Menu
  open={openMenu}
  anchorEl={anchorEl}
  onClose={onClose}
  PaperProps={{ sx: { width: "350px" } }}
>
  <MenuList ref={menuContainerRef}>
    <MenuItem >
      <ListItemIcon>
        <SafetyCheckOutlinedIcon fontSize="small" />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText>Your data in YouTube</ListItemText>
    </MenuItem>
    <Divider />

    <MenuItem onClick={handleClick}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <DarkModeOutlinedIcon fontSize="small" />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText>Appearance:Device theme</ListItemText>
      <KeyboardArrowRightOutlinedIcon />
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <LanguageOutlinedIcon fontSize="small" />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText>Language:English</ListItemText>
      <KeyboardArrowRightOutlinedIcon />
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <AdminPanelSettingsOutlinedIcon fontSize="small" />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText>Restricted Mode:Off</ListItemText>
      <KeyboardArrowRightOutlinedIcon />
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <TranslateOutlinedIcon fontSize="small" />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText>Location:Germany</ListItemText>
      <KeyboardArrowRightOutlinedIcon />
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <KeyboardOutlinedIcon fontSize="small" />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText>Keyboard Shortcuts</ListItemText>
    </MenuItem>
    <Divider />

    <MenuItem>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <SettingsOutlinedIcon fontSize="small" />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText>Settings</ListItemText>
    </MenuItem>
    <Divider />

    <MenuItem>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <HelpOutlineOutlinedIcon fontSize="small" />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText>Help</ListItemText>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <FeedbackOutlinedIcon fontSize="small" />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText>Send Feedback</ListItemText>
    </MenuItem>
  </MenuList>
</Menu>
```